# Sql convert string with comma separator to double

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert '-35,321.42' to '35321.42' in sql ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to just convert it to `money`:

```
select cast('-35,321.42' as money)
```

If you want this in a different type, then you can convert that:

```
select cast(cast('-35,321.42' as money) as decimal(10, 2))
```

For instance.

The equivalent of "double" in SQL Server is `float` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)), so you can do:

```
select cast(cast('-35,321.42' as money) as float)
```